# rvest Web Scraping: Getting http form from site with web-shell-spinner

Tags: html, r, http

I'm attempting to extract a  form from the following site:
'https://app.qbo.intuit.com/app/login?loadCustomerAssistanceAssets=us&product=qbOnline'

[image]

However, it seems that these is a web-shell-spinner preventing me from doing so.

```
# Get url
main_url <- "https://app.qbo.intuit.com/app/login?loadCustomerAssistanceAssets=us&product=qbOnline"

# Connection
session.1 <- session(main_url)
http_response <- html_form(session.1)
```

When running just the html_form(session.1) line I get an empty list:
[image]

Im pretty sure it has something to do with the web-spinner on the QuickBooks site:
[image]

Any thoughts on how I can extract the form and POST HTTP request to login?

Thanks,

Comment: The problem is you seem to be using rvest and rvest cannot execute javascript. That form you are seeing is most likey generated via javascript and is not in the the actual HTML page source. What you see in the "Elements" tab is not necessarily what is loaded. Be sure to check the "Sources" tab for the files that rvest would actually be able to see. If you need to interact with pages that use JavaScript, you'll need to use something like RSelenium instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can navigate to the page, enter your username in the form and click on the "sign-in button".

```
library(RSelenium)

url <- "https://app.qbo.intuit.com/app/login?loadCustomerAssistanceAssets=us&product=qbOnline"
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj_Username <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '//*[@id="ius-signin-userId-input"]')
web_Obj_Username$sendKeysToElement(list("myusername"))

web_Obj_Signin <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '//*[@id="ius-identifier-first-submit-btn"]')
web_Obj_Signin$clickElement()
```